# Списки отображения

Tags: python, opengl

Ребята, вопрос простой, но точно я на него ответ не могу найти (или понять). Есть в OpenGL понятие - список отображения, в нем во время инициализации один раз рисуются все заявленные точки, а точнее выполняются команды GL, а потом, если вы повторно его вызываете, то моделька просто копируется без повторного расчета. Все вроде ясно, но... я гружу модель из файла `.obj` и, соответственно, прорисовка его осуществляется у меня через цикл:

```
def draw(self):
    for v in range (0,len(self.verts),4):
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex3f( (  self.verts[v])[0],   (self.verts[v])[1],  (self.verts[v])[2])
        glVertex3f( (self.verts[v+1])[0], (self.verts[v+1])[1],(self.verts[v+1])[2])
        glVertex3f( (self.verts[v+2])[0], (self.verts[v+2])[1],(self.verts[v+2])[2])
        glVertex3f( (self.verts[v+3])[0], (self.verts[v+3])[1],(self.verts[v+3])[2])
        glEnd()
```

Отсюда встает вопрос, если это я помещу в список, будет ли достигнуть тот оптимизационный эффект, который должен быть достигнут по средством применения списков отображения. Формально: будут ли запомнены все `glbegin`, или при вызове списка, каждый раз будет запускаться цикл, и проще все оставить как есть?

[Списки отображения](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/opengl/displaylists.xml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование списков отображения могло бы быть эффективно только лишь в том случае, когда вы **действительно много** раз подряд выводите **один и тот же объект**, но, скажем, с разными параметрами матрицы `WVP.` Поскольку в вашем случае модель грузится из `.obj` файла, то на каждую новую модель придется строить свой список отображения, что, предполагаю, *неприемлемо.*

---

Сейчас, когда на смену фиксированному пайплайну в продуктах промышленного уровня пришел пайплайн вида `Vertex Buffer Object` + набор шейдеров, использование списков отображения *не в учебных целях* вряд ли может кого-либо заинтересовать.

Почитайте про [**Vertex Buffer Object**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object) - более производительного средства просто не найти.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ)))